# Newtonian approximation for the tidal forces at the event horizon of a black hole

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, newtonian-gravity, black-holes

I'm currently working on a problem where I have to calculate the tidal forces a person experiences if their feet touches the Schwartzschild radius and their head is $1.8m$ elevated above the Schwartzschild radius.

Our professor told us that it is reasonable to use the Newtonian approximation for the acceleration, i.e.
$$a = -\frac{M}{r^2},$$
with the reasoning that the length scale of the Schwartzschild radius is much larger than the $1.8m$ of the person (We need to calculate it for a black hole with $20$ solar masses).

I have some trouble understanding this reasoning. If I'm not mistaken the acceleration is given in the Schwartzschild metric as
$$a=\frac{M}{r^2\sqrt{1-\frac{r_s}{r}}}$$
which only becomes the expression for the Newtonian acceleration in the limit $r \gg r_s=2M$. In our problem, $r$ will be pretty close to the value $r_s$ so I thought this approximation should not hold...

I would be really glad if someone could point out where my thinking process is wrong and how I should rather think about the argument from my professor...

Comment: Ah sorry, you're right! Typed too fast, I corrected my error.

Comment: I believe much depends on whether your observer is inertial or not.

Comment: Your *a* is the proper acceleration aka the specific force *F/m* for a stationary observer, while *1/r²* is the force-free *d²r/dτ²* of a free falling observer.